# association with a model that doesn't have primary key id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am on Rails 2, which the newest version of factory_girl to use is 1.2.4

I have 2 tables:

ethnicities(**code**, description)
people(**id**, name, ..., *ethnicity_code*, ...)

people.ethnicity_code is the foreign key

In factory_girl factories.rb:

```
Factory.define :ethnicity
  f.sequence :code { |n| n+20 }
  f.description 'Foo'
end

Factory.define :person do |p|
  p.name 'So and so'
  ...
  p.association :ethnicity_code, :factory => :ethnicity
  ...
end
```

My models have the correct associations set and "set_primary_key :code"

When I do `Factory(:person)`, I always get an insert error due to the foreign key constraint. It would seem that it's getting an incorrect primary key from the association. Factory girl creates the ethnicities record fine, but it's trying to insert a value of "1" as the ethnicity_code in the people table.

Comment: glad to help! (I wish I knew about ruby-on-rails so I could help you with your error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be barking up the wrong tree here but I suspect the problem is that `p.association :ethnicity_code ...` should be `p.association :ethnicity ...`. I.e., you name the association as defined in the model rather than the foreign key column.

Comment: ok yea! i thought i had tried that and it was bombing out, but it seems to work now! thank you!